# How to print "readily movable" articulated elephant using Creator Pro 2?

Tags: flashforge-creator

I watched many clips showing printing of an articulated elephant model (e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeYPL1SUAjc&t=3s) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzYmEpxOHtM)). It seems that those printed elephants can move their legs straight out of the printer without any effort to force the leg to move.

I try printing the exact same elephant model using Creator Pro 2 in the default setting. After finished, the legs of the resulting elephant model stick with its trunk. I have to apply a very strong force to initially move its legs (which almost breaks the bridge between its legs).

So, I wondered if my Creator Pro 2 can print perfectly and readily movable elephant. What setting should I apply to achieve this result?

Comment: Can you tell whether it was stuck on on the first layer - or on all layers?
Sounds like it may mostly be slicer issues, e.g. "elephant's foot" (pun not intended) preventing movement.

Comment: It seems that the bottommost layer of elephant's trunk was molten onto the topmost layer of the elephant's legs, which blocks the movement of both legs. There is a gap between each leg and the trunk without support. Chances are these unsupport portion of the bottommost layer of trunk will place onto the leg.

Comment: can you show a photo?